# aiomysql makes random errors in events appear

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

so far I've been using `mysql.connector` to manage mysql in my discord bot, however, since that's not async, I'm trying to change to `aiomysql`. It works, kinda... I'm having a problem where *sometimes* I get something like

```py
ERROR:asyncio:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <ClientEventTask state=pending event=on_raw_message_delete coro=<bound method LoggingSystem.on_raw_message_delete of <cogs.loggingsystem.LoggingSystem object at 0x059C7A48>>>
```

In this case it was in `on_raw_message_delete` of a cog, but the event where this happens isn't always the same and it's only on events, never in commands.

So the question is, am I doing something wrong that may cause that?

```py
# mysqlconnection.py

pool: aiomysql.Pool = None

async def getpool():
    global pool
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host="", user="", password="", db="", pool_recycle=0)

async def execute_search(search: str, vals: tuple = None): # This function is what I use to get data from the DB across the whole bot
    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
        async with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            if vals is None:
                await cursor.execute(search)
            else:
                await cursor.execute(search, vals)
            result = await cursor.fetchall()
    return result

async def execute_alter(query: str, vals: tuple): # This function is what I use to alter data in the DB across the whole bot
    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
        async with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute(query, vals)
            await connection.commit()
```

```py
# bot.py

from mysqlconnection import execute_search, execute_alter, getpool

@bot.listen()
async def on_ready():
    await getpool()
    ...
```

So, anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: Please post the whole traceback.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński That's the problem, that's all I have... There's literally nothing more to show